# on modal's button call controller and Redirect to action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a modal.

**Html:**

```
<div>
  //this is modal content
</div>
```

When a button is clicked in modal I call controller's action

**JavaScript :**

```
$(function() {
    $("#Yes").click(function () {
        $.get('/myController/myAction/@Model.Id');
    });
});
```

Here is **controller's** action

```
public ActionResult myAction(Guid id)
{
    //do some stuff
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Currently I get forwarded to controller's action but the controller's action `RedirectToAction` doesn't redirect me to `Index` action. I stay on same page with modal.

Something I should do?
or am not doing right?

Comment: instead of button directly write <a> tag bcoz you are doing only redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $("#Yes").click(function () {
        $.get('/myController/myAction/@Model.Id', function( data ) {
        window.location.href='@Url.Action("myAction","myController")'
     });
});
```

Comment: that worked thanks! Will accept it when I'm allowed to(after 5 mins).

Answer (score 0):

Then why are you redirection to index action just give the address of current page

```
return RedirectToAction("<current page ref>");
```